# changing the height and width of an image - android

Tags: android, imageview

I am making an android application that person can post some text and an image to the server and then others can see the photo but I want to change the height and width of the photo but I don't have the idea how to change it. Should the size be changed before sending or it should be changed after getting it from the server. If anyone has the idea to change it after getting it from the server please tell me to post the other class too.
Here is the class by which I send the data to the server. Any help !

```
package naqibshayea.afghanbazaar;


public class insert_ads extends AppCompatActivity {

private String url_insert_Ads , seller1;

private String[] id;
private String[] name;

private EditText title , intro ,  seller ,  phone;

private TextView selected_cat , selected_img_txt;

private ImageView selected_img;

private Spinner my_spinner;

private String[] selected_cat_info = new String[2];
ProgressDialog pDialog;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_insert_ads);

    getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById( R.id.app_bar );
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    selected_cat = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.txt_insert_ads_selected_cat );
    selected_img_txt = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.insert_ads_selected_img_txt );
    selected_img = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.insert_ads_selected_img );

    title = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.insert_ads_title );
    intro = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.insert_ads_intro );
    seller = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.insert_ads_seller );
    phone = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.insert_ads_phone );

    my_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.insert_ads_spinner);

    /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();

    url_insert_Ads = data.getString("url");

    seller1 = data.getString("UNAME");

    seller.setText(seller1);

    id = data.getStringArray("cat_id");

    name = data.getStringArray("cat_name");

    ArrayList<String> cats = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < id.length ; i++)
    {
        cats.add(i , name[i]);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adb = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , cats);

    my_spinner.setAdapter(adb);

    my_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long _id) {

            selected_cat_info[0] = id[position];
            selected_cat_info[1] = name[position];

            selected_cat.setText(name[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
}



private int my_requestCode = 1;
private Bitmap myBitmap;
private String my_finalImage;

public void onBtnCameraClick(View v)
{
    if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        startActivityForResult(intent, my_requestCode);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , getString(R.string.no_camera_error) ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if ( requestCode == my_requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Bundle e = data.getExtras();

        myBitmap = (Bitmap) e.get("data");

        show_captured_image();
    }
   else if (requestCode == My_requestCode_gallery && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri image = data.getData();

        show_internal_image(image);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , getString(R.string.get_image_error) ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

public void show_captured_image()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder imageLoader = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.full_screen_image , (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.full_img_layout_root));

    ImageView bigImage = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.full_img_img);

    bigImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

    TextView imageTitle = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.full_image_title);

    imageTitle.setText(R.string.captured_img_title);

    imageLoader.setView(layout);

    imageLoader.setCancelable(false);

    imageLoader.setPositiveButton(R.string.captured_img_btn_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            selected_img.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

            selected_img_txt.setText(R.string.captured_img_is_true);

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    imageLoader.setNegativeButton(R.string.captured_img_btn_again, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            onBtnCameraClick(null);
        }
    });

    imageLoader.setNeutralButton(R.string.btn_Back_to_home, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    imageLoader.create();

    imageLoader.show();
}

private int My_requestCode_gallery = 2;

public void onBtnGalleryClick(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK , MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(i, My_requestCode_gallery);
}

public void onImageClick(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, My_requestCode_gallery);
}


public void show_internal_image(final Uri imageUri)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder imageLoader = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.full_screen_image , (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.full_img_layout_root));

    ImageView bigImage = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.full_img_img);

    bigImage.setImageURI(imageUri);

    TextView imageTitle = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.full_image_title);

    imageTitle.setText(R.string.captured_img_title);

    imageLoader.setView(layout);

    imageLoader.setCancelable(false);

    imageLoader.setPositiveButton(R.string.captured_img_btn_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            selected_img.setImageURI(imageUri);
            selected_img_txt.setText(R.string.captured_img_is_true);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    imageLoader.setNegativeButton(R.string.captured_img_btn_again, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            onBtnGalleryClick(null);
        }
    });

    imageLoader.setNeutralButton(R.string.btn_Back_to_home, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    imageLoader.create();

    imageLoader.show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_insert_ads, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.cancel_post)
    {
        finish();
    }

    if (id == R.id.share_post)
    {
        if (title.getText().length() > 1)
        {

            if (intro.getText().length() > 1)

            {
                if( seller.getText().length() > 1 )
                {
                    if (phone.getText().length() > 1)
                    {
                        if (selected_cat.getText() != getString(R.string.insert_ads_form_sel_cat_text)){

                            if (selected_img_txt.getText() != getString(R.string.insert_ads_form_error_sel_cat)){

                                Bitmap image =( (BitmapDrawable) selected_img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

                                HashMap<String , String> my_data = new HashMap<>();

                                my_data.put( "title" , title.getText().toString() );
                                my_data.put( "intro" , intro.getText().toString() );
                                my_data.put("seller", seller.getText().toString());
                                my_data.put("phone", phone.getText().toString());
                                my_data.put("cat", selected_cat_info[0]);


                                UploadImage upload = new UploadImage( my_data , image , this );

                                upload.execute();

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , R.string.insert_ads_form_error_sel_img , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , R.string.insert_ads_form_error_sel_cat , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        phone.setHint(R.string.insert_ads_form_error_hint);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    seller.setHint( R.string.insert_ads_form_error_hint );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                intro.setHint(R.string.insert_ads_form_error_hint);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            title.setHint(R.string.insert_ads_form_error_hint);
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Void , Void ,Boolean>
{
    private Context main_con;

    private HashMap<String , String> main_hm;
    private Bitmap main_image;

    public UploadImage(HashMap<String , String> hm , Bitmap image , Context con)
    {
        main_hm = hm;
        main_image = image;
        main_con = con;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(insert_ads.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("درحال آماده سازی");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        main_image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG , 100 , outputStream);

        String encoded_image = Base64.encodeToString(outputStream.toByteArray() , Base64.DEFAULT);

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();

        dataToSend.add( new BasicNameValuePair("title" , main_hm.get("title") ) );
        dataToSend.add( new BasicNameValuePair("intro" , main_hm.get("intro") ) );
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("seller" , main_hm.get("seller") ) );
        dataToSend.add( new BasicNameValuePair("phone" , main_hm.get("phone") ) );
        dataToSend.add( new BasicNameValuePair("cat" , main_hm.get("cat") ) );
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", encoded_image));

        HttpParams myHttpParams = new BasicHttpParams();

        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myHttpParams, 1000 * 30);

        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myHttpParams, 1000 * 30);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient( myHttpParams );

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost( url_insert_Ads );

        try {

            post.setEntity( new UrlEncodedFormEntity( dataToSend , "UTF-8"));

            client.execute( post );

            return true;

        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            /*
             * Log.i( "MatiMessage" , "error in posting data -> " + e.toString() );
             */
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
    {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        String message = "";

        if( result == true )
        {
            message = getString( R.string.result_of_insert_message_success );
        }
        else
        {
            message = getString( R.string.result_of_insert_message_failure );
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder( main_con );
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setTitle(R.string.result_of_insert_title);
        alert.setMessage(message);
        alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_Back_to_home,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
        );
        alert.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After receiving your Bitmap resize the image and set onto your imageview.

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.picture);
Bitmap resizedBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
iv.setImageBitmap(resizedBmp);
```